# Why does my MasterPage UpdatePanel call a Page_Load on my ContentPage?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, master-pages

My code in my MasterPage is causing a full page_load on my content pages every 5 seconds. Sadly, that means it is breaking some of my content pages and how they are programmed. My hope was that a separate UpdatePanel would allow only that region to be updated and not refresh the other UpdatePanels and resources on the content pages.

I've attempted moving the Timer out of the UpdatePanel, changing the UpdatePanel to UpdateMode="Conditional" and even using a third party AjaxPanel (Telerik).

All results are the same, the content page reloads every 5 seconds clearing the title template (Shown below) and sometimes breaking some functions on the site.

Until I can figure out a way to ONLY have the literal update without reloading the other resources I have to leave the Timer disabled.

I'll be happy to post more code if needed, but I didn't want to provide information that may not have any importance.

MasterPage - Site.Master

```
<title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.Net Site</title>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMenu" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <span>Tickets<asp:Literal ID="LiteralUnassignedTickets" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
        <asp:Timer ID="TimerAutoRefreshMenu" runat="server" Interval="5000" Enabled="true"></asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Are you sure that an UpdatePanel is a good idea? What about implementing AJAX polling? Or better yet - use [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) to notify clients of a change as soon as it happens.

Comment: Honestly, I'm just going with what I thought I knew! Maybe I should invest in something else. However, the entire project is in ASP.Net, using UpdatePanels and LINQ. I'd rather not be the guy who brings something else to the table if it is possible to make it work using the current tech in the project.

Comment: UpdatePanel is one of the worst parts of Web Forms. Anything you can do to move away from UpdatePanel (and Web Forms) would be a good thing. Especially in this case. It will simplify your page logic (you won't have to filter out partial postbacks), you won't have to use polling to retrieve updates (less client and server processing time, less wasted bandwidth), users will get their updates faster, and the volume of data sent across the wire. Using SignalR for this is exactly what it was designed to do.

Comment: Well my friend, it looks like this 3 day weekend I'm going to be reading! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you have to use update panels make the update panel update conditional and set the timer as an asynchronous trigger(very important).
update panels are even worse when they are on master pages then when they are on the content page
a better option for minimal change is setTimeout to a function that does an ajax call to update the number of unassigned tickets. you can grow this to update a whole bunch of fields/elements using a json object. Plus the techniques can be very useful if you move to MVC.